# How to know Html Request Recieved in win form?

Tags: c#

Im working on a win form project that I should get some information from specific URL.
I mean I should listen to this url : 
`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/getsms` 
and when It will change to
 `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/getsms?Destination=$Destination&Source=$Source&ReceiveTime=$ReceiveTime&MsgBody=$MsgBody`
and I have to parse the contex as well.

so how can I know when exactly there is a request in this url?

Is it a good way that I use httpListener? Its my code for that:

```
public static void SimpleListenerExample(string[] prefixes)
{

    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    // Add the prefixes. 
    foreach (string s in prefixes)
    {
        listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
    }
    listener.Start();
    //Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request. 
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

    // Obtain a response object.
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    // Construct a response. 
    string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>";
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
    // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    // You must close the output stream.
    output.Close();
    listener.Stop();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] test = { "http://www.damavand.co.ir:80/" };
    SimpleListenerExample(test);
}
```

but it has not worked. I dont know why. It dosent have any error, but I cant get any response. should I set any server configuration? How? and how can I test my program that I be sure there is a request.

Thanks for any response ...

Comment: I don't see `8080` anywhere in your code...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by listen to a url. do you mean you are listening to requests made to this url?